# Running chsh does not change shell

Tags: shell, zsh, users

I want to change my shell from bash to zsh.

I have tried running the following while logged in as user zol:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh zol
$ su -c 'chsh -s /bin/zsh zol'
# The above all results with:
$ password:
$ chsh: Shell not changed.

# zsh exists in /etc/shells.. 
chsh -l
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/sbin/nologin
/bin/zsh
```

What could be wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try running 'chsh' without any arguments as zol?

Comment: Are you using something like ldap/nis etc.?

Comment: Much more importantly: Why doesnt it give you more info?  
That message might be fine for a seasoned sysop but for most people it's downright rude.  Im facing the same problem 5 years on, and people wonder why linux has spent the past 20 years not on the desktop.

Comment: You expected your shell to change instantly? You change your _login shell_ with `chsh`, which means you will have to log in again.

Comment: No, this is not the reason why Linux has not made it. I actually has taken over the world, most systems on the planet now use a Linux kernel (chances are that your cellphone does), pretty much all webserver, cloudserver etc.. use Linux. But there is a lot of old crap in Linux that needs reform badly. Some of these commands are 30 years old and they are not userfriendly by any measure. Since it is Opensource, it is up TO US to fix this and build something better.

Comment: I was working with VSCode and seems it keeps a separate default shell (independent of the system shell)...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

User account modifications will not be saved if you have opened /etc/passwd (vim /etc/passwd) when you try to change the info.

Alternative: try with usermod (as zol):

```
$ usermod -s /bin/zsh
```

or

```
$ sudo usermod -s /bin/zsh zol
```

If this doesn't work either, edit `/etc/passwd` by hand.

```
sudo vipw
# set zol's shell to /bin/zsh
:wq
```

Comment: please use `vipw` instead of `vim` as they set the appropriate file locks.

Comment: "User account modifications will not be saved if you have opened /etc/passwd" — but why?

Comment: It doesn't work too. When I restart Linux virtual machine (centos7), it's OK now!

Comment: @fromnaboo Can you please explain why you make this claim in your first sentence, as @ Thanatos already asked ? You have not provided any explanation about this, and this seems to spawn out of nowhere, as is.

Answer (score 16):

Just ran into this. No matter what I did logging in and back out would not change my shell yet it was listed in /etc/shells and in /etc/passwd.

finally it dawned on me: Maybe I am logged in with another session?

So I did

```
# who
```

and it validated I did have indeed other open sessions from other machines:

```
dom  pts/0        Nov 6 13:53 (10.1.6.121)
dom  pts/1        Nov 5 12:30 (10.1.6.165)
dom  pts/2        Nov 4 12:33 (10.1.6.197)
```

I then did:

```
pkill -KILL -u dom
```

I was immediately logged out and after logging back in: Voila! Shell was changed

Comment: It works, why "logged in with another session" create a problem?

Answer (score 8):

If you see `chsh: Shell not changed.`, it could mean that the shell was already changed.

Check which shell is listed:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep `cd; pwd`
```

If it's correct, log out and back in to have the change take effect.

Comment: Thanks! This was my rookie mistake. I had to log out and log in again for the change to take place.

Answer (score 3):

When to run "chsh -l" if you to see:

```
/usr/bin/zsh
/bin/zsh
```

Then use:

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

Warning: The commands was run on Fedora 25, In **ubuntun** the option "-l" from is out.

Comment: `-l` is an invalid option for me. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Sorry, I don't give information about the distro where the commands work. In my case I tested on Fedora 25. I try on ubuntu and I verify the option "-l" is out.

Comment: Regardless, `chsh -s` worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: The option is valid on Manjaro but it still refuses to change the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Change it from `/etc/passwd`

I had some problems with zsh (that is default in manjaro) and I used it for get back to bash.

```
[infinito@manjaro ~]$ grep infinito /etc/passwd
infinito:x:1000:1000:Sergio N:/home/infinito:/bin/bash      <---here
```

Comment: please don't post text as image, you might want to use `grep infinito /etc/passwd`